# Why do my blogger posts have blurry thumbnails on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, blogger, photos

I am a novice.

I have searched through previous questions.

When I share a blogger post to Facebook, the thumbnail is pixelated.

The photos are larger than 200 X 200.

I get this error message on Facebook's Object Debugger: Object at URL 'http://www.nameofmyblog.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because a required property 'og:image:url' of type 'url' was not provided.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are facing this problem then do not share your Blogger Post directly with the help of SHARE Button.**

**Instead you copy the URL of your post and then paste that URL in the Status or Comment section.**

Comment: Hi zackygaurav: Your suggestion worked. However, is this the only way to do it? Do I need to change my share buttons on the blog? Are you a web genius that can help me?

Comment: Hi @loadedtrain I am not a web genius. I also own a website powered by Blogger. [iTech Valley](http://www.itechvalley.in/). You should try changing your share button. **Facebook provides you the original share button.** Follow this link and try it out. [Facebook Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)